# Get number after matching string bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have some parameters that the user can pass to the command, but I need to get the number following a specific string.

Here are some examples of the parameters I am passing to the bash script

```
 xxx.sh   cpus="12" memory="1500mb"
 xxx.sh  -cpus 12 -memory 1500mb
 xxx.sh  cpus=12 memory=1500mb
```

I would like to search for the first occurrence of cpus and return the number 12.

The number could be any where from 1 to 1000.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement your own version of `getopts` - I suggest you look at what's already available before doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex in your script:

```
[[ $* =~ cpus[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zD7uO3/2)

This will print `12` for all the command line arguments shown in your question.

This will match `cpus` followed by 0 or more non-digits and then it matches and captured 1 or more digits in captured group #1 i.e. `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use this little snippet for long options in bash.
the `pv` function (print variable) i only use for debugging.

```
#!/bin/bash

function pv () {
  echo "$1: ${!1}"
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case $1 in
    -m|--memory) mem=$2; shift ;;
    -c|--cpus) cpus=$2; shift ;;
    *) ;;
  esac
  shift
done

pv cpus
pv mem
```

You can also use this bit if you are only interested in short options:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts tx: opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        t) TEST="-test" ;;
        x) FOO="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) ;;
    esac
done

echo "TEST = $TEST"
echo "FOO  = $FOO"
```